# Different ways to completely remove a package ? Am I getting this right?

Tags: apt

Do these two commands do the same thing ?

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pkg

sudo apt-get purge --autoremove pkg
```

My understanding is that they both do the same things:

(1) Delete pkg.
(2) Delete dependencies of pkg that are no longer needed.
(3) Delete all the files that came with pkg and pkg's dependencies..

Am I getting this right ?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

This will remove orphan packages + the files that came with it.

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove pkg
```

This will purge pkg and then runs `apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

Those two commands are indeed equivalent, as can be seen with `man apt-get`.

> ```
> remove --purge is equivalent to the purge command.
> ```

Comment: what do they do though ?

Comment: The user is asking about **autoremove --purge**

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
apt-get remove --autoremove pkg
```

According to the manpage, --auto-remove/--autoremove only works for command install and remove.

Comment: Try it with `-s`, you will see it accepts the flag with `purge` too (makes sense as "purge acts like remove")